# How to catch elements from a txt including blank space?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a text file with data that I would like to extract including blank space, this is my code to do that:

```
pppath=r'C:\Users\1017249739\Desktop\JALG\JALGINT\NUEVO_PROYECTO_V0\LEARNING_SWAT\example_for_Colombia_JALG\SWAT_SAMANA\WEATHER_DATA\Valores minimos diarios de temperatura\23085110_EL PENOL.txt'

path=[pppath]
stations={}
serie_data={}
year={}
T_min={}
for i in path:
    lista=[]
    with open (i,'r+') as f:
        lines=f.readlines()
    stations['Estacion '+str(''.join(lines[4][112::].split()))]=[int(lines[4][103::].split()[0]),'Estacion '+str(''.join(lines[4][112::].split())),int(lines[6].split()[1])/100 if lines[6].split()[2]=='N' else -int(lines[6].split()[1])/100,-int(lines[7].split()[1])/100 if lines[7].split()[2]=='W' else int(lines[7].split()[1])/100,float(lines[8].split()[1])]
    serie_data['Estaciones']=stations
    c=-1
    listaux=[]
    calm=[]
    for line in lines:
        c=c+1
        if ' DIA       ENERO *  FEBRE *  MARZO *  ABRIL *  MAYO  *  JUNIO *  JULIO *  AGOST *  SEPTI *  OCTUB *  NOVIE *  DICIE *' in line:
            start=c
        if '** DATOS PRELIMINARES **'  in line:
            end=start+36
            listaux.append(lines[start:end-2])
            calm.append([start,end-2])
```

When you run this script and you see the variable `listaux`, specifically `listaux[16][3]` it has just two values but if you see in the text, efectively there are two values, but the others is empty, but I need to catch that blank space and save it, it's to say:

From text file I have this:

```
************************************************************************************************************************************
          DIA       ENERO *  FEBRE *  MARZO *  ABRIL *  MAYO  *  JUNIO *  JULIO *  AGOST *  SEPTI *  OCTUB *  NOVIE *  DICIE *
************************************************************************************************************************************

           01        11.6                       10.8
           02        10.8                       11.2
           03        11.2                       10.4
           04        10.4                       11.6
           05        11.6                       11.8
           06        11.2                       10.6
           07        10.6                       11.0
           08        11.0                       11.4
           09         9.6                       11.6
           10        11.4                       11.2
           11        10.0                       10.8
           12        10.6                       12.0
           13        11.0                       11.8
           14         9.8                       10.2
           15        10.4                       11.2
           16        11.2                       11.0
           17        10.0                       11.8
           18        10.4                       10.8
           19         8.2                       11.4
           20         9.4                       10.4
           21         9.8
           22        10.8
           23        11.4
           24        10.6
           25        10.8
           26        11.2
           27         9.8
           28        10.2
           29        10.2
           30         9.4
           31        11.0

MEDIA                18.3 3   18.4 8   18.4 8   18.5 3   18.9 8    *       19.0     18.5     17.6     17.8     17.6     17.4 3
```

Then this is that I got:

```
listaux[16][3]='           01        11.6                       10.8\n'
```

Finally I want this:

```
listaux[16][0].split()=['DIA','ENERO','FEBRE','MARZO','ABRIL','MAYO','JUNIO','JULIO','AGOST','SEPTI','OCTU','NOVIE','DICIE']
listaux[16][3].split()=['01','11.6',' ',' ','10.8',' ',' ',' ',' ,' ',' ',' ',' ']
```

Comment: Is the data always in the same format? Is the spacing always the same? Or is this just a one time thing?    As a side note. I'm not typically one to complain about line length. but one of your lines is almost 400 characters long... It makes it very difficult to read.

Comment: I guess, yes, that kind of format that i showed before repeat on and on according how long were measured the variables, but when i read as a .readlines() the length of every line seems different but if you see the txt it is not. So i don't know if this information could help, i also i have the original txt file, but i don't know how to share it through this media